# eBPF TC Program for IPv6 Outgoing Packets Drops Packets with MSS > 1424 and MTU 1500 When Adding Extension Header

Tags: linux, networking, ebpf, packet-loss, mss

I'm currently working on a TC eBPF project where our objective is to add an extension header to all outgoing IPv6 packets. The setup involves an environment where the Maximum Segment Size (MSS) is set above 1424, and the network MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) is configured at 1500.

The issue arises when we attempt to increase the packet size. We are using the bpf_skb_adjust_room function to add an additional 16 bytes to the packet. However, when the MSS is greater than 1424, these modified packets get dropped, with the error 'Packet Size too Big'.

Comment: Packet size too big is an ICMP error for the packet (not the segment). An MTU of 1500 means the IPv6 packet cannot exceed 1500. Subtract the IPv6 header 40 bytes, and the extension header size (you did not list). What is left over is the maximum size of the TCP segment you are allowed to have, including the TCP header (20 to 60 bytes, depending on options). You seem to be exceeding the 1500 byte MTU.

Comment: "_We are using the bpf_skb_adjust_room function to add an additional 16 bytes to the packet._" By the way, 16 bytes is not enough for an extension header considering that you need eight bytes for the Next Header and eight bytes for the Header Extension Length, then you have the header data.

Answer (score 1):

You can decrease your tcp mss value based on your extension header size. There are scenarios where [encapsulated packets could exceed MTU](https://www.imperva.com/learn/application-security/what-is-mtu-mss/). This can be solved by setting mss accordingly either on switches or on server.